# Unity 2.0 XML configuration possible?

Tags: unity-container

Is it possible to use custom XML to store unity container configuration in my IoC class library project?

I dont want to store the IoC config at the startup project (WPF project).

Regards
Bryan

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration to load an arbitrary file, but you'll need to do that yourself - the simpler overloads will go to the appdomain's config file by default.

If you have the Unity source code, you can look in the Unity\Tests\TestSupport.Unity\Configuration\ConfigFileLoader.cs file for an (perhap overly complex) example. There we pull a config file out of a resource, dump it to disk, and then load it via ConfigurationManager.